# How to read the length of a string in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I created the following table with one text column:

```
create table table1 (
  col1 varchar2(20)
);
```

Then I inserted [one Polish letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%84) to it:

```
insert into table1 values ('ą')
```

How can I obtain the number of characters in this string? It should be 1, but all functions that I know return other results:
`LENGTH(COL1)`  -> 2,
`LENGTHC(COL1)` -> 2,
`LENGTH2(COL1)` -> 2,
`LENGTH4(COL1)` -> 2,
`LENGTHB(COL1)` -> 6.

The `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;` returns:

```
PARAMETER              VALUE
---------------------------------
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION      18.0.0.0.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP    FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS   BYTE
NLS_COMP               BINARY
NLS_SORT               BINARY
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET       AL32UTF8
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY       AMERICA
NLS_TERRITORY          AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE           AMERICAN
...                    ...
```

You can check it on: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c3ab067b52cbf825840ca0356fa28a3f).

Comment: `select dump(col1) from table1` shows that the character is stored in six bytes. I can't reproduce that either on my own computer or on livesql; that's a question for dbfiddle. Did you try it on your own computer, or only on dbfiddle?

Comment: Seems like an Oracle 18.4 bug (which dbfiddle is using). It works for me on 12.1, 12.2 18.7, 18.10 and 19.8

Comment: I was testing it only on dbfiddle. Thank you - this solves the problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - to me it seems more likely that it's a dbfiddle bug (perhaps in how it reads characters from its web interface, or whatnot) rather than an Oracle bug, regardless of version.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a bug with the version of Oracle you are running the query on or an issue with the character being encoded on the web server.

I have almost all of the same NLS parameters on my system except I am on Oracle 19 instead of 18.

[image: toad screenshot]

Even on [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/) it returns the results as you would expect but again, that database is on Oracle 19.

[image: livesql screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. Now I am testing SQL queries on https://livesql.oracle.com/ and they works properly.